# Determine the range of values in one raster associated with certain values in another raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, overlay

I have two rasters, one with thematic data, and the other with continuous data (floats).  I am trying to calculate/determine the the range of float values associated with the different classes in my thematic raster.  For instance, in my thematic raster, I have a class A.  If there are 5 cells in my continuous raster data that overlay thematic cells of class A, and these 5 cell have values of 1.2, 3.7, -4.5, 6.23, -0.8, I would like the end result of my calculation to show:

```
Class A:  Range [-4.5 to 6.23]
Class B:   .....and so on.
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this?  I've been trying to determine if the raster overlay tools in ArcMap can provide this, but I haven't come across a solution yet.  I'm hoping to avoid a very complicated equation in the raster calculator.

Another way to produce the analysis I am looking for would be to generate a histogram for each thematic class in one raster based on the associated (overlaid) values in another.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Zonal Statistics as Table (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) should work for you. In your case, the range will be represented by the min/max values within the table.

[image]